# Maximum a posteriori estimation using Java

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have the following Java function:

```
/**
     * Calculates the Probability of the user being in the currently observed
     * RSS values and the RSS values for a specific location.
     * 
     * @param l1
     *            RSS values of a location in radiomap
     * @param l2
     *            RSS values currently observed
     * 
     * @return The Probability for this location, or MIN_VALUE for error
     */
    public static double calculateProbability(ArrayList<String> l1, ArrayList<String> l2, float sGreek) {

        double finalResult = 1;
        float v1;
        float v2;
        double temp;
        String str;

        for (int i = 0; i < l1.size(); ++i) {

            try {
                str = l1.get(i);
                v1 = Float.valueOf(str.trim()).floatValue();
                str = l2.get(i);
                v2 = Float.valueOf(str.trim()).floatValue();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
            }

            temp = v1 - v2;   
            temp *= temp;
            temp = -temp;

        temp /= (double) (sGreek * sGreek);
        temp = (double) Math.exp(temp);

        finalResult *= temp;
    }
    return finalResult;
}
```

It calculates the MAP or MSSE probability between observed RSS values and RSS in a radio map. I'm currently trying to find the literature where this functions comes from. Does anyone knows which equations were used for probability in this code?

Comment: How do you "have" this code?  Perhaps the place and/or author it came from has information about its genesis.  Have you checked?

Comment: this are the slides that came with the code: http://www2.ucy.ac.cy/%7Elaoudias/presentations/cwspi2012_slides.pdf the equations shown there do not make any sense with this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you trace through the code, it gives that finalResult $\displaystyle = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \exp\left({\dfrac{-\left(v_i^1-v^2_i\right)^2}{\sigma^2}}\right)$ where $v^1_i, v^2_i$ are the $i$th values from l1 and l2, respectively.

Comment: yes I reached the same formula, the problem is, how are we going to obtain probabilities (MAP) with that formula? I don't seem to find a relation with the existing literature (for example the wikipedia article)

Comment: The exponential term is almost the probability density function for a normal distribution.

Comment: where can I read more about that?

Comment: [Normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) and [probability density function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function).

Comment: Thank you Harbert, the PDF formula of a gaussian distribution is expressed as: http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/5/6/4/564914214ead956aceccd30b78d2f6ee.png which is not exactly as the previous formula used trough the code. do you know why they are ignoring the other elements on the formula? thank you!

Comment: I don't know why they are being ignored, which is why I said it is almost the PDF.